# Defining your javascript classes with Unique Class names

Tags: javascript

I'm in the process of building a "custom" javascript library to use across different projects.  The library will be built incrementally i.e. the new classes (functions) will be added as the need arises.

The issue which I'm facing is ensuring that my function name doesn't conflict with other developer's function names.  I have thought of the following options, and would like the community to find pros and cons of each.  Note each option will make use of the prototype pattern to define classes.

Option 1:

1. Define classes (function) with your company name append infront of it.

Example:

```
Mycompany.Dept.Js.Class = function()
{
    this.Member1 = 3;
}

MyCompany.Dept.Js.ClassA.prototype.PerformOperation = function()
{
 return this.Member1;
}

MyCompany.Dept.Js.ClassB = function()
{
    this.Member1 = "Test";
}

MyCompany.Dept.Js.ClassB.prototype.GetValue = function(){ return this.Member1;}
```

Usage:

```
var obj1 = new MyCompany.Dept.Js.ClassA();
obj1.PerformOperation();

var obj2 = new MyCompany.Dept.Js.ClassA();
obj2.GetValue();
```

Issue:  I have to use the full class name to define my objects.

Option 2:  Module Pattern.

```
var MyCompany.Dept.Js = function() //IIFE
{
    var ClassA = function() 
        { 
         this.Member1 = 33;
        }`

    var ClassB = function() 
       {
         this.Member1 = "Test";
         }

    ClassA.prototype.PerformOperation = function(){//do something;}
    ClassB.prototype.GetValue = function(){//do something;}

    return {
            BuildObject:function(type)  
           {
               if(type=="ClassA") return new ClassA();
               if (type == "ClassB") return new ClassB();
            }

         }
}();
```

Usage:

```
var obj1 = MyCompany.Dept.Js.BuildObject("ClassA");
var obj2 = MyCompany.Dept.Js.BuildObject("ClassB");
obj1.PerformOperation();
obj2.GetValue();
```

Questions:

Do you see any issues with approach # 2.  What are some of the cons?  Is there any other technique?

Comment: My biggest concern with both approaches is probably the  MyCompany.Dept.Js convention since it make it seem as if no code can be shared between departments. I recommend namespacing based on feature/context instead

Comment: Yes, always use the module pattern. It just makes everything easier by giving you a dedicated, controllable scope.

Comment: Note that you can replace the "." in the above names with any other legitimate identifier character and achieve exactly the same level of name clash safety (e.g. `MyCompany_Dept_Js`). As TGH says, keep names short and group by functionality, not business area.

Comment: Idk, I'd have to do some benchmarking to check speed, but I'd build one master Class object, and use it to store/mitigate clashes. E. G.  If I define Class('Some.class') and after my code someone defines the same class name,  have it throw a console error. What you do with duplicates is sort of up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  MyCompany_Dept_Js was just used as an example.  I agree we need to group classes by functionality.